# How do I evaluate $\int \frac{dt}{t(t^2+1)} $

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I evaluate $$\int \frac{dt}{t(t^2+1)} $$

I tried several methods, but without success (I am just a beginner with the craft of integration)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with partial fractions?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with it, I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to decompose that fraction into others that are easy to integrate.

Notice that $\frac{1}{t(t^2+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2t}{t^2(t^2+1)}$ and that $2t=(t^2)'$. This suggests $x=t^2$. We will get $\frac{1}{x(x+1)}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{-1}{x+1}$

Comment: @AlonAlon Recall the change of variable formula $\int f(g(t))g'(t)dt=\int f(x)dx$. Here $g(t)=t^2$. In the right-hand side the $g'(t)=2t$ disappears.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

First substitute $u=t^2$, then use partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

use that $\frac{1}{t(t^2+1)}=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{t^2+1}$
we will get $\ln(t)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(t^2+1)+C$
make the ansatz
$\frac{1}{t(t^2+1)}=\frac{A}{t}+\frac{Bt+c}{t^2+1}$ where $A,B,C$ are real numbers

Comment: How can one figure this out? Is there a systematic way doing it?

Comment: @AlonAlon That is a very nice question. Yes, there is a systematic way. There is an algorithm. It is not extremely short, but if you learn it you will be able to solve most integrals in school. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Answer (score 1):

Let $t = \tan(\theta)$ with $dt = \sec^2(\theta)d\theta$. Then $$\int \frac{1}{t(t^2+1)}dt =\int \frac{1}{\tan(\theta)(\tan^2(\theta)+1)}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta \\ = \int \frac{1}{\tan(\theta)(\sec^2\theta)}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta \\ =\int \frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}d\theta \\ = \int \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}d\theta$$ Now letting $u =  \sin(\theta)$ and $du =  \cos(\theta)d\theta$ you get the very easy integral $$\int \frac{du}{u}$$